# Bootstrap: add margin between columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put extra margin space between columns on my Bootstrap grid layout.
I've tried adding custom CSS class like this

```
.classWithPad {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

but didn't solve my problem, also I've tried adding `ml-1` and `mr-1` but I didn't get desired. Here is my code:

When I tried to add some extra margin/padding the corresponding column is moved to a new row.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row mt-4 justify-content-between">

  <div class="col-md-4 card border-radius-15 bg-shadow pt-3">
    <h5>General Information</h5>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 pr-0">
        paragraphs...
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 pl-0 text-right">
        paragraphs...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 card border-radius-15 bg-shadow pt-3">
    <h5>Features</h5>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 pr-0">

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 pl-0 text-right">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 card border-radius-15 bg-shadow pt-3">
    <h5>Game Manufacturers</h5>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 pr-0">

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 pl-0 text-right">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally don't want to mix structural and presentation elements. In this case, you've combined columns with cards. Put the cards inside the columns, and if you wanted them full-height you can use `h-100` on them.

That, along with the container that should be present around outer rows, and you're all good. If you want more spacing, use `px-*` classes on the columns.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mt-4 justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card h-100 border-radius-15 bg-shadow pt-3">
        <h5>General Information</h5>
        <hr/>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 pr-0">
            <p>paragraphs...</p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 pl-0 text-right">
            <p>paragraphs...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card h-100 border-radius-15 bg-shadow pt-3">
        <h5>Features</h5>
        <hr/>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 pr-0">
            <p>paragraphs...</p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 pl-0 text-right">
            <p>paragraphs...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card h-100 border-radius-15 bg-shadow pt-3">
        <h5>Game Manufacturers</h5>
        <hr/>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 pr-0">
            <p>paragraphs...</p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 pl-0 text-right">
            <p>paragraphs...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```